# Unity can't acess prefab's script's variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a 3D game on Unity but recently a problem occurred. I can't access a variable from another prefab's script. I tried it before when the object which has to be accessed wasn't a prefab and it worked correctly.

This is the script which tries to access the "slashtime" variable, but when I run it gives back 0 though in the other script the variable is changing continuously.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sword;
    public float slashtime;



    private void Update()
    {
        slashtime=sword.GetComponent<movement>().slashtime;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {



        if (collider.tag == "sword" && slashtime+1f > Time.time)
        {

            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `slashtime = sword.Find("movement").GetComponent<movement>().slashtime;`?  Just a newbie guess, as I'm just starting to learn Unity myself, but the pattern seems to require finding the GameObject by name, and *then* grabbing its script component which is a separate thing even if they have the same name.

Comment: you should do the initialization on `start` and then access the variable in update

Comment: Please don't call `GetComponent` in `Update`. It's an expensive operation and the result should be cached whenever possible, so call it once in `Awake` and store the result as a field.  Also, we have no idea how your `movement` component is defined. Please include that in your question. Finally, C# convention is to name classes in capitalized form like `Collision` or `Movement`. You should also call your class something different than `collision` or `Collision` to avoid programmer confusion with Unity's [`Collision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! And some completion: in my movement method I have the slashtime public float which changes value after the player pressed the left mouse button and the movement class is also public, Also if i dragged the sword prefab into the script so it should work without find method am I right?

Comment: Sidenote, these aren't "prefabs" whose variables you're accessing. They are instantiated components.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reworking your code a bit, with explanations below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _sword;
    private float _slashTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        _slashTime = GameObject.Find("Movement").GetComponent<Movement>().GetSlashTime();
    }    

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {           
        if (collider.CompareTag("sword") && _slashTime + 1f > Time.time)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); // What is gameObject in this context?  the _sword?  something else?
        }
    }
}
```

1. Use private properties.  Why?  Because it increases modularity and protects the object(s) you're working with from accidentally having their values overwritten.
2. In conjunction to this, use public methods to obtain/change the values in other objects.  Public methods are your API.
3. It's convention to begin the names of private properties with an underscore.
4. Like I said in my comment above, you first need to `Find()` your desired object before you can attempt to `GetComponent<T>()`.
5. Like others have said, attempting to `GetComponent<T>()` in `Update()` is computationally expensive.  It's better to get that component at `Start()` and then talk to it as necessary (in this case, during collision).
6. `CompareTag()` is the more modern/accepted way to check a tag.

EDIT:

`[SerializeField]` will keep the property private while also making it available to the Unity editor.  It's good for debugging and linking objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to say that I referenced the sword prefab in the inspector by dragging it in.

Comment: so add [SerializeField] in front of the private

Comment: Thank you, everyone! You were right, I should be more organized and use properly the public and private variables and object names so I don't make any mistake like this again. Thank you again and have a good night/day!

Comment: @MajorProductions this grabs the `_slashtime` only **once** though and looking at the usage and how OP retrieved it before it rather seems that this value is changing over time and needs to be updated in `OnTriggerEnter`. Instead of storing the `_sword` as `GameObject` I would rather store a reference to the `Movemet` component. If OP is then even able to drag it in via the Inspector as he said you can completely get rid of all the expensive `Find` and `GetComponent` calls!

Comment: To 6. `CompareTag` is not only more modern/accepted but adds more security! It throws an exception if the given string is not even a valid tag (e.g. if you have a typo) something that `==` simply hides as it fails silently! Also in general **if** you want to compare strings directly you are almost always better using `string.Equals` instead. `CompareTag` is also sliiiightly faster but the first reason is the essential one ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this. It is also working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;    

public class collision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject sword;
    public float slashtime;

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        sword = collider.gameObject;
        slashtime=sword.GetComponent<movement>().slashtime;
        if (collider.tag == "sword" && slashtime+1f > Time.time)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

- Reason for your code is not working because when you write some code in update then it calls every frame. so when your object is destroyed, update call that code and it shown error.

Comment: actually no need to store the `slashtime` not the `sword` value though. However I would rather store the `_sword` directly as a `Movement` so OP can directly drag it in via the Inspector. Them you can get rid of the `GetComponent` entirely